Django Admin Custom Add
Say I have a model called Book:
class Book(EOModel):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, blank=False)
    subtitle = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    open_library_key = models.CharField(max_length=32, null=True, blank=True)
    ...
    location = models.ForeignKey(Order, null=False, blank=False, on_delete=models.PROTECT)

The Book model has a classmethod to craete an entry using openlibrary ID.
@classmethod
def from_open_library(cls, open_library_key: str, location: Order) -> Self:
    data = open_library_get_book(open_library_key)
    ...
    book.save()
    
    return book

So given a correct openlibrary ID and an Order object from_open_library would create a new entry.
My question is, how can I implement an django admin page for it? Can I add a "add via openlibrary" next to the actual add button? The page has a char field to get the ID and dropdown would list the Orders to select.

If you need to specify extra data, that is not very trivial. Django's actions typically only work with one (or more) records.

So the only solution would be to create custom views? Which TBH is not that complex.

no. Move the logic to the model layer.
